# Sending video to Telerate 9" Green Monitor

Tags: hardware, crt-monitor, terminal, composite-video

I found an old Telerate green monitor at a thrift store and figured I could run my computer output through an HDMI -> AV converter with no problem, or a Raspberry Pi composite output signal. Turns out that isn't the case. The monitor will display the HDMI/AV converters test screen, but not my actual computer signal. As for the Raspberry Pi composite signal, won't display anything. I connected a camcorder via the camcorders 3.5mm AV output, and that did display video brilliantly. Just connected a cheap DVD player from the VIDEO OUT port, that worked as well.

Dying to use this thing as a terminal, what needs to be set in the Raspberry Pi config to make the composite output the same as that of a camcorder or DVD player, or is it impossible using a Raspberry Pi. In that case, is there another microcomputer that will display to the screen?

DVD output:
[image: DVD output]

Back of the unit:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is off-topic because it's about how to configure a modern Raspberry Pi or how to use a modern HDMI to composite converter on a modern PC. The retro monitor apparently  works fine.

Comment: *Dying to use this thing as a terminal* - it's a monitor, not a terminal.  Or do you mean to build a terminal, using the monitor, Pi, and a keyboard?

Comment: This site has accepted questions about how to configure emulators if the answer imparts something meaningful about the emulated computer. So I think more nuance is needed to persuade that this is off-topic.

Comment: @another-dave yeah, that's the idea

Comment: If you're having trouble getting video output from a Raspberry Pi, the [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) is where you want to be posting.

Comment: @cjs per the accepted answer, the issue had entirely to do with video termination, nothing whatsoever to do with the Pi. It was an analogue problem from analogue signal times.

Comment: @Tommy It is to do with the Pi because most devices with analogue video output like that are not bothered at all by lack of 75 Ω termination beyond producing a slightly brighter than usual signal. (I own _dozens_ of such devices with 15.7 kHz video output on an RCA connector, and I've never seen any of them stop generating output due to lack of termination.)

Comment: @cjs then clearly the makers of that monitor were *incredibly* forward-sighted.

Comment: @Tommy I have no idea what you're trying to say there. There was and is nothing unusual about switchable termination: many monitors for commercial use and virtually all PVMs had it. (All three of mine do.) The only unusual thing here is that _just_ the Pi seems to detect an unterminated video output line (which, as I mentioned, is not usual for contemporary devices--I'd say virtually unknown) and seems not to generate a signal in that case. It's not even usual on modern devices as far as I'm aware; as you mention your HDMI/AV converter does not have this problem.

Comment: @cjs I don’t own an HDMI/AV converter, or indeed anything with an AV input. The accepted answer overtly mentions that this is not a Pi-specific problem. Since you seem to think it is in error, would suggest you start directing comments to its author.

Comment: @Tommy You've got it backwards: the accepted answer mentions that this is indeed specific to some devices: "Some sources might be able to detect when a TV is connected, and will output video only when connected. Without proper termination the sources will not see a device being connected." I can imagine someone adding such a feature to a Raspberry Pi; I've never seen anything like that on many, many contemporary devices generating video.

Comment: @cjs yes, it is a feature specific to some devices, across at least the entire period between that screen’s manufacture and now. The issue is unambiguously not “getting video out of a Raspberry Pi”, this feature is not unique or custom to the Raspberry Pi — indeed it was producing proper video the whole time. The problem was: some analogue video sources require termination due to analogue properties of analogue video, and this was always true.

Comment: @Tommy No, this is where you've gone _very_ wrong. CVBS analogue video will work fine from most devices into a monitor that has a hi-Z input (i.e., does not have 75 Ω termination). I do have done this between literally dozens of different computers and half a dozen or more different monitors. The only difference is that the image will be a little bit brigther than it should be. ¶ If a CVBS video output works into a 75 Ω but not  a hi-Z input, that's definitely an issue with the source device doing something unusual that contemporary sources do/did not do. (Unless the monitor is broken.)

Comment: In short: user cannot very get video on old display with Raspberry Pi. Reason turns out to relate to an option on old display. Fix is to adjust old display. @cjs insists this is a Raspberry Pi question.

Comment: @Tommy The "fix" may be to change the termination, but that is because the _Raspberry Pi_ requires it. You can't say that it's not a Raspberry Pi issue when no (or almost no) other hardware, contemporary or modern, requires this fix. You'll note the question even stated that the modern HDMI to CVBS converter did not require this and that the problem was only with the Pi.

Comment: @cjs again, your false belief, even with weasel words added at the last moment, that “no (or almost no) other hardware … requires this fix” is trivially contradicted by the presence of the switch on the TV. Your theory is that they added cost in order to support “no … other hardware”? Or do you think there was a genuine reason, **at the time** which did not involve thinking about a product that wouldn’t exist until decades later?

Comment: It's not at all contradicted by the switch on the TV: you simply have no idea of the switch's purpose, which is to maintain proper termination and signal quality when one monitor connected to an output. (This switch is often automatic on monitors with a pass-through output; Sony PVMs for example disable termination when you plug a cable into the pass-through output, which is why you should not plug a cable into that output unless it's plugged into another properly terminated monitor.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is unsure if this will help, but it might just be the monitor after all.

The termination switch on the monitor is incorrect.

It must be set to 75 ohms. It is currently set to no termination which allows loop through to many devices.

Some sources might be able to detect when a TV is connected, and will output video only when connected. Without proper termination the sources will not see a device being connected.

So there is likely nothing wrong with the modern sources and they don't need any configuration to make them work.

Comment: This was it. Swear I had messed with this switch while sending the video before, guess not. Interesting though, what does termination mean in this context?

Comment: In short, it relates to transmission line theory of coaxial cables and thus how video is transmitted throgh coaxial cables. Video signals sent over coax are intended to be terminated by having with a 75 ohm resistor at the receiving end of the coaxial cable.

Comment: Nice catch! That’s not easy to see

Answer (score 9):

If you can see the test screen from the converter, the converter is generating a signal the monitor understands, but the converter does not understand the input from the computer.

You are most likely giving it a signal in a higher resolution and/or refresh rate than it understands, and it apparently cannot tell the computer what it likes or the computer doesn't listen.  Read the documentation carefully to see what resolution you should choose.  An educated guess is something corresponding to television standard resolution - that is 480i or 576i.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/480i for details.

Comment: Downvoted, why?

Answer (score 5):

> The monitor will display the HDMI/AV converters test screen, but not my actual computer signal.

Guess: The timing for your actual computer signal is wrong, probably because the HDMI input your are presenting has the wrong resolution, or is not interlaced, or whatever.

Do you have any documentation for your HDMI/AV converter? Can you experiment with different resolutions?